# How can I compare an exact string in a data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am attempt to modify an ex-coworker's code written in Python using data frames.

We want to remove all rows from the data frame `df_msc` that don't contain one of the `drives_tup` strings in the "Mounted" column.  He wrote it trimming it down using the string modifiers `startswith` and `endswith`, but this is still passing through unwanted rows.  Is there a way to do something like `string.isequalto(drives_tup)`?

I'm not good with Python so I don't want to change the format too much as I fear it will break other parts of the code...

```
      # Take only those drives where they start or end with one of the drives_tup values
      drives_tup = ("/usr/asm", "/data/reserved", "/var", "/", "/data/diagnostics")
      df_msc = df_msc.iloc[:, 1:-1].dropna(how='all')
      df_msc = df_msc.loc[df_msc['Mounted'].str.startswith(drives_tup)]
      df_msc = df_msc.loc[df_msc['Mounted'].str.endswith(drives_tup)]
```

Comment: `df_msc['Mounted'].isin(drives_tup)`

Comment: Can you share more of the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
df_msc = df_msc.loc[df_msc['Mounted'].isin(drives_tup)]
```